# Is there any difference between <xsl:copy> and <xsl:element name="{name()}">?

Tags: xml, xslt

I'd like to know if there's any difference between:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

and:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is at least one difference. Given the following input:

```
<root xmlns="htpp://www.example.com/my">my text</root>
```

this template:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

will produce:

```
<root>my text</root>
```

while `xsl:copy` will copy the element with its namespace preserved:

```
<root xmlns="htpp://www.example.com/my">my text</root>
```

---

**EDIT**
In response to comment by @parakmiakos:

Given the following input:

```
<my:root xmlns:my="htpp://www.example.com/my">my text</my:root>
```

this template*:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:element name="{name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

will produce:

```
<my:root xmlns:my="htpp://www.example.com/my">my text</my:root>
```

(*) provided that "my" prefix is declared in the stylesheet.

This template:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

will produce:

```
<root>my text</root>
```

and this one:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

will return:

```
<my:root xmlns:my="htpp://www.example.com/my">my text</my:root>
```

same as the first one (but without having to declare the prefix).

Comment: I think that by using name() instead of local-name(), he would preserve the namespace.

Comment: Interesting, the tool I was using didn't work that way.

Comment: @parakmiakos: What tool are you using, then?

Comment: Then I assume Tibco Business Works does not adhere to the XSLT specification in this regard. You should consider filing a bug report.

Comment: If you don't specify a `namespace` attribute to `xsl:element` then the `name` is interpreted according to the namespace bindings in force in the _stylesheet_, not those in the original document.  If you want to preserve the namespace from the original input you have to say `<xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">`

Comment: @parakmiakos Do you know which processor is being used? You can find out by including `<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor')"/>` in your stylesheet.

Comment: @michael.hor257k I get : TIBCO Software, Inc. As an additional note, I cannot go through with the transformation, unless I explicitly declare the element's namespace in the xsl file. Must be a bug indeed.

Comment: `fn:name() Returns the name of the current node or the first node in the specified node set`
`fn:local-name() Returns the name of the current node or the first node in the specified node set - without the namespace prefix`
from : http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp                           So indeed, in your case, where there is no prefix, you should get that output. However if you add a prefix, you get this result:
http://xsltransform.net/6qM2e2b/3               whereas this is the correct syntax: http://xsltransform.net/6qM2e2b/4

Comment: @parakmiakos I have added a clarification to my answer. However, this is about the difference between `name()` and `local-name()`; while OP was asking about the difference between `xsl:element` and `xsl:copy`. And no, having to declare the prefix in the stylesheet is not a bug.

Comment: @michael.hor257k yes I know this wasn't the original question, but I thought it should be clear to anyone else who reads this. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The `xsl:element` element generates a new element node.

`xsl:copy` copies a context item to the output sequence. However, the said context item does not have to be an element node. In your case:

```
<xsl:template match="/*">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

The context item is indeed an element. This has the following consequences:

- `xsl:copy` also copies the element's namespaces if any
- an optional sequence constructor inside `xsl:copy` is used if the context item is an element. In your example, the sequence constructor is `<xsl:apply-templates/>`

**Summary**: `xsl:copy` can copy *any* kind of node (atomic value, document, element, text, attribute, processing instruction, comment, namespace) whereas `xsl:element` is solely capable of generating element nodes.

**Usage**: Use `xsl:copy` to effectively copy nodes from input XML to the output sequence. Use `xsl:element` only if element names are *dynamic*, that is, not known beforehand.

As an aside note, with XSLT 2.0 you can control the treatment of namespaces explicitly with the attributes `copy-namespaces` and `inherit-namespaces`.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is apparent when you have namespace declarations in scope (other than the namespace of the element that you are copying).  Using `<xsl:copy>` will copy any in-scope namespace nodes, using `<xsl:element>` won't.  So given an input file of

```
<root xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <foo/>
</root>
```

a stylesheet of

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*/*" />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="foo">
    <xsl:copy/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

you will get output of

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" />
```

because `<xsl:copy>` has copied the in-scope namespace nodes from the input element.  Whereas if you use

```
  <xsl:template match="foo">
    <xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}"/>
  </xsl:template>
```

you will get

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo/>
```

As [Matthias points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21677397/592139), in XSLT 2.0 you can say `<xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">` to suppress the copying of in-scope namespaces - for an element node, `<xsl:copy copy-namespaces="no">` has the same effect as `<xsl:element name="{name()}" namespace="{namespace-uri()}">`